# selenium issue trying to retrieve text from a div using driver.findElement(By.xpath()

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to verify a few things on a page and have a grid with header columns. I want to grab the text from those are part of the verification. For some reason it's returning empty and I don't understand why considering I'm using contains text to find the element.

```
     String expectedName = "Employee Name";
     String actualName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Employee Name')]")).getText();
     Assert.assertEquals(expectedName, actualName);
```

The error I get is this: `java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Employee Name] but found []`

The HTML:

```
<div class="dx-datagrid-text-content dx-text-content-alignment-left dx-header-filter-indicator" role="presentation">Employee Name</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be close. To extract the *textContent* of the `<div>` element ideally you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String expectedName = "Employee Name";
  String actualName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.dx-datagrid-text-content.dx-text-content-alignment-left.dx-header-filter-indicator"))).getText();
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedName, actualName);
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  String expectedName = "Employee Name";
  String actualName = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='dx-datagrid-text-content dx-text-content-alignment-left dx-header-filter-indicator']"))).getText();
  Assert.assertEquals(expectedName, actualName);
  ```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution as there's no need to wait for the element to be visible. If the element wasn't already visible, `String actualName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Employee Name')]")).getText();` would throw an error, would it not?

Comment: Hmmm, you are finding an element by it's text _Employee Name_ and then you are using `getText()` to extract the same text _Employee Name_? Can you tell us more about your usecase?

Comment: What do you mean by "usecase?" This is a sanity check to make sure the screen loads as it should and data is populated. I thought I would first confirm a few of the column headings are visible then check for the expected data. Is that what you're looking for? I don't care how I find the element, contains text seemed the cleanest way.